# Delete multiple lines from text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea and I want to delete multiple lines when the user clicks the button.

Example

I have the next in the text area;

```
Australia - Mobile Optus
Australia - Mobile Telstra
Australia - Mobile Vodafone
Australia - Special
Australia - Sydney
Austria
```

And I want to delete de line 0,3,4

The result must be like this:

```
Australia - Mobile Telstra
Australia - Mobile Vodafone
Austria
```

I think getting first the rows

```
var rows = document.querySelector('textarea').value.split("\n").length
```

But I'm stuck, I can't figure out how to make it

:s

Comment: Why exactly `0,3,4`?

Comment: The input always gonna have the same amount of lines(rows), the only that's gonna change is the content, but the rows numbers always gonna be 43. And the lines that will remove always gonna be the same.

For example, I have this input

`Austria
Mexico
USA
Brazil
Canada`

Then remove the lines 0,3,4

`Mexico
USA`

Another example

`Colombia
Cuba
Ecuador
France
Germany`

Then remove the lines 0,3,4

`Cuba
Ecuador`

Comment: Positional deletion is rather fragile; it would be better to remove lines based on their textual content; in that case, if the position ever changes, your code doesn't need to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array.prototype.splice(start, count)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) inside a reverse iteration

```js
function removeLines(EL, arr) {
  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b); // Sort, just in case you messed the order
  const lines = EL.value.trim().split(/\n/);
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) lines.splice(arr[i], 1);
  EL.value = lines.join('\n') 
  return EL.value ;
}

const EL_text = document.querySelector('#text');
const EL_rem = document.querySelector('#rem');

EL_rem.addEventListener('click', () => removeLines(EL_text, [4, 0, 3]));
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * {margin:0; box-sizing: border-box;}

textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<button id="rem" type="button">Remove 0,3,4</button>
<textarea id="text">
0 Australia - Mobile Optus
1 Australia - Mobile Telstra
2 Australia - Mobile Vodafone
3 Australia - Special
4 Australia - Sydney
5 Austria
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you apply the split without calling "length" then you receive an array that contains the lines of your textarea, for example:

```js
var rows = document.querySelector('textarea').value.split('\n');

console.log(rows)
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea">
Australia - Mobile Optus
Australia - Mobile Telstra
Australia - Mobile Vodafone
Australia - Special
Australia - Sydney
Austria
</textarea>
```

So, to remove specific elements from an array you can use the prototype splice

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

ex:

> array.splice(start, deleteCount)
>
> start: The index at which to start changing the array.
>
> deleteCount: An integer indicating the number of elements in the array
>   to remove from start.

```js
var rows = [
"Australia - Mobile Optus",
"Australia - Mobile Telstra",
"Australia - Mobile Vodafone",
"Australia - Special",
"Australia - Sydney",
"Austria"
]

rows.splice(2,1);
rows.splice(4,1);

console.log(rows)
```

I share Article with different ways to remove elements from an array: https://love2dev.com/blog/javascript-remove-from-array/